# Accessing SugarCRM Global variable $current_user from a custom Javascript file v6.5

Tags: javascript, php, sugarcrm

How can I access global SugarCRM variables from a custom javascript file that I have attached to a field on the `DetailView` in SugarCRM V6.5.

Specifically, I want to access the `$current_user` global PHP variable from the Javascript file.

I have added the javascript file by editing the `custom/modules/Accounts/views/detailviewdef.php` and then editing the array to look like this

```
array (        0 => 
    array (
      'file' => 'modules/Accounts/Account.js',
    ),
  1 => 
    array (
      'file' => 'custom/modules/Accounts/Account1.js',
    ),
  ),
```

The details that i want to access from the `$current_user` is actually a customization that I made to the `User` module to add more configuration option for every user.

I saw somewhere else on Google that i could use `var current_user = current_user;` in the custom Javascript file and it actually shows the user ID of the logged in user, however what i really want is to get the User detail Object, please does anyone have any ideas.

Regards

Comment: if the answer helped you should accept it, that way you get points also

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to write a controller that send back the whole current_user data in json.

custom/modules/Accounts/controller.php

```
class AccountsController extends SugarController{
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function action_getCurrentUser(){
        echo json_encode($GLOBALS['current_user']);
    }
}
```

And in your js file call it like this:

```
var request = $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php',
        data: {
            module: 'Accounts',
            action: 'getCurrentUser',
            to_pdf: true, // this reduces the response so that json works
        },
```

Comment: Hi @Pauel, thanks for your response. If i create the controller in the  Accounts module for instance `custom/modules/Accounts/controller.php` how do i get SugarCRM to call the new action that am adding, in your case - `action_getCurrentUser()`. I thought the action needs to be registered beforehand?

Comment: does it answer your question or can I help you

Comment: @user980643 Please accept my answer if it helped you solving you problem.